# Problema entre PHP 7.4 y PHP 8.2 en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema entre versiones de PHP 7.4 y PHP 8.2 en MySQL al cambiar a la versión PHP8.2
ya no funciona un INSERT en MySQL pero solo lo hace en este modeloClass(CajaChica) ya que
si en otro modulo si lo hace.

Diferencia es que estan en carpetas diferentes, el único cambio que realice fue la versión de PHP por que antes de eso no tuve problemas...

Quite codigo para resumir por que solo esta linea es la que causa probles y no se por que...

`ejecutarConsulta($bitacora);` en `classCajaChica.php` al llamarlo desde este archivo...

```php
<?php
require('PVMod.php');
require('../modelos/CajaChica.php'); #Este tiene ../

$TituloP = 'Producto';
$classPV = new PuntoVentaMod();
$classCajaChica = new CajaChica();

switch (GET('op')) {
  case 'FinPV':

    if ($tipoPago === '0') {
      $tipoPago = null;
      #Agregar efectivo a CajaChica
      $resultado = $classCajaChica->corteCajaChicaID();
      if (
        $resultado['idCajaChica'] != NULL 
        and is_numeric($resultado['idCajaChica'])
      ) {
        $resultado = $classCajaChica->corteCajaChica(
          $resultado['idCajaChica']
        );
      } else {
        $resultado['corte'] = 0;
      }

      $bitacora = "Venta #$idventa por $$Acumulatotal";
      $corte = $resultado['corte'] + $Acumulatotal;

# Error 2024 01 14 (No se por que no inserta valores en la bitácora, todo se ve bien solo no lo hace).
# Lo causa la verción el PHP no se por que a un...  PHP 7.4  PHP 8.2
# Aqui no funciona por eso lo comento....
# $classCajaChica->agregarCajaChica("Venta #$idventa", $Acumulatotal, $corte, 'null', $bitacora);
# Aqui omito la consulta y funciona...
      $classCajaChica->agregarCajaChicaVenta("Venta #$idventa", $Acumulatotal, $corte, 'null', $bitacora);

      #/ Agregar efectivo a CajaChica 

    #Verifca los resultados de todo el proceso para pruebas.
    $verifica = '
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">' . $inVeFi . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">' . $inPrVe . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">' . $acPrCa . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">' . $acRe . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">' . $quPV . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
    $verifica = null; #Borrar verrificar = null...
    #echo $verifica;

    echo $table;
    break;

  default:
    echo "LD. $host$rutaFile";
}
```

Aquí pongo classCajaChica...

```php
<?php
#Incluímos inicialmente la conexión a la base de datos
require_once "../config/Conexion.php";

class CajaChica
{

  #Variables para nombres generales en el Modelo...
  public $tablaDB = "cajaChica";
  private $caracteres_malos = array(
    "'", '"', '<', '>', '\\', '/', '!', 
    '¡', '#', '$', '%', '&', '¿', '?', '|', '`'
  );

  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  public function agregarCajaChica(
    $descripcion,
    $monto,
    $corte,
    $ajuste,
    $bitacora
  ){
    $query = 
    "INSERT INTO `$this->tablaDB` 
      (`idusuario`, `idcontrol`, `fecha`, `descripcion`, `monto`, `corte`, `ajuste`) "
      . "VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['idusuario'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['idcontrol']
      . "', NOW(), '$descripcion', '$monto', '$corte', '$ajuste');
    ";

    #Guardar accion en bitacora para llevar un registro.
    $queryR = str_replace($this->caracteres_malos, '', $query);
    $bitacora = 
    "INSERT INTO `bitacora` 
      (`fecha`, `accion`, `descripcion`, `MySQL`, `recupera`, `idusuario`, `idcontrol`) "
      . "VALUES (NOW(), 1, '$bitacora', '$queryR', NULL,  '" . $_SESSION['idusuario']
      . "', '" . $_SESSION['idcontrol'] . "') 
    ";

# Cuando realiza INSERT INTO de bitácora es cuando se cae todo...
# Entonces para solución temporal en lo que encuentro el problema no realizo esta tarea...
# La consulta MySQL ya la revise y todo esta bien ya la puse directamente en el MySQL y no marca ningun problemas.. 
    ejecutarConsulta($bitacora);
    #Aqui ya no paso si lo mando a llamar desde PV.php

    return ejecutarConsulta($query);
  }

  public function agregarCajaChicaVenta($descripcion, $monto, $corte, $ajuste, $bitacora)
  {
    $query = 
    "INSERT INTO `$this->tablaDB`
      (`idusuario`, `idcontrol`, `fecha`, `descripcion`, `monto`, `corte`, `ajuste`) "
      . "VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['idusuario'] . "', '" . $_SESSION['idcontrol']
      . "', NOW(), '$descripcion', '$monto', '$corte', '$ajuste');
    ";

    #Aqui la omito para evitar el problema... ejecutarConsulta($bitacora);

    return ejecutarConsulta($query);
  }
}
```

Este es la conexión

```php
<?php
require_once 'global.php'; # Solo una ves se requiere

$conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

mysqli_query($conexion, 'SET NAMES "' . DB_ENCODE . '"');

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, DB_ENCODE);
#Establece el conjunto de caracteres predeterminado del cliente.

#Si tenemos un posible error en la conexión lo mostramos
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
  #if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexion)){
  printf(
    PRO_NOMBRE . " - Falló conexión a la base de datos "
    . DB_NAME . ": %s\n",
    mysqli_connect_error()
  );
  validaConn();
  exit();
}

if (!function_exists('ejecutarConsulta')) {

  function ejecutarConsulta($query)
  {
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($query);
    return $query;
  }

} else {
  echo 'Error archivo Conexion PHP.';
}

#echo '<br />config/Conexion.php Linea Final.';
```

Aquí pongo el otro modulo que también lo ocupa y no tiene el problema al llamar a la Class $classCajachica->agregarCajaChica()...

```php
<?php
require("../modelos/CajaChica.php");

$classCajachica = new CajaChica();
$TituloP = 'Registro';

switch (GET('op')) {

  case 'agregarCajaChica':
    if ($accion == '0') {
      $monto = (-1 * $monto);
      $bitacora = "Agregar egreso de $$monto- a caja chica.";
      $accion = 'null';

    } elseif ($accion == '1') {
      $bitacora = "Ajuste de caja, de $"
        . Fmoneda($resultado['corte'])
        . "- al nuevo monto de $$monto-";
      $descripcion = trim("$bitacora $descripcion");

    } elseif ($accion == '2') {
      $monto = (-1 * $monto);
      $bitacora = "Corte de Caja por $$monto-";
      $descripcion = "$bitacora $descripcion";
    }

    $corte = $resultado['corte'] + $monto;

    if ($accion == '1') {
      $corte = $monto;
      $monto = 0;
    } else {
      $resultado['corte'] === null
        ? $corte = $monto
        : $corte = $resultado['corte'] + $monto;
    }

    #Aqui lo mando a llamar normal como antes y funciona tanto en PHP7.4 como en 8.2

    $classCajachica->agregarCajaChica(
      $descripcion,
      $monto,
      $corte,
      $accion,
      $bitacora
    );
    break;

  default:
    echo "LD. $host$rutaFile";
}
```

Comment: asi a primera vista los string interpolation tienen un formato deprecated ver https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dollar_brace_string_interpolation

Comment: puede q el sql q estas pasandole como string a bitacora rompa el insert `$queryR` , proba meterlo en un try catch para ver/logear el error a un archivo https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531703/1423096

Comment: Ya cheque la interpolación de cadenas $ puse la consulta directa lo mas básica que se puede pero por sus Hu... no lo hace estoy implementado ver los errores a ver si sale algo hay !

Comment: Ya cheque los errores y no hay nada entre las fechas son errores de cuando estaba localizando el problema 
[11-Nov-2023 22:08:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /home/*****/*****.*****/login.php on line 9
[25-Jan-2024 02:25:49 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "echo" in /home/*****/*****.*****/pv/pvAJAX.php on line 320 8:::(

Comment: para debugear un "error" podes usar `error_log($string);` onda  `error_log( print_r($query, true));` justo antes del `return $query`; `error_log($queryR);` ; un clásico es `error_log(print_r([__FUNCTION__, func_get_args()],true));`  justo antes de una función que hace muchas cosas. eso te va a dar pistas que que fue lo que falló cuando falla y si decidis refactorizar en base a eso emprolijar un poco.

Comment: al margen... yo aprovecharía para pasar el tema base de datos a PDO prepared statements y/o buscar un query builder liviano via composer cosa de no andar peleando con el code en el futuro

Comment: Hola. ¿Imprimiste y revisaste el valor de `$query` en la función problemática? ¿Probaste a insertar directamente esos datos en la BD, para descartar problemas de clave duplicada u otros? Tu programa es demasiado *optimista*, no hay prácticamente ningún control de errores ni de riesgos. Considera usar consultas preparadas, bloques `try ... catch` y asegurarte de que ciertos datos existen antes de pasar a usarlos directamente...

Comment: ... Para evitar problemas con las cadenas puedes usar `sprintf`, el cual permitirá además una escritura más limpia de código. Por ejemplo:  `$bitacora = sprintf("Agregar egreso de $%s a caja chica.",$monto);`. Otro ejemplo, aunque para este caso lo mejor sería una consulta preparada, además de verificar los datos en sesión:  ``$query =sprintf( "INSERT INTO `%s` (`idusuario`,`idcontrol`,`fecha`,`descripcion`,`monto`,`corte`,`ajuste`) VALUES ('%s', '%s',NOW(),'%s','%s','%s','%s')",$this->tablaDB,$_SESSION['idusuario'],$_SESSION['idcontrol'],$descripcion,$monto,$corte,$ajuste);``

Comment: cual es el contenido de $query  en caja chica? de seguro ese string que es el query de Insert, tiene algun problema de sintaxix...

Comment: No ya puse la consulta directamente en MySQL  no hay problema con respecto a que las llaves primarias duplicadas descarte eso poniendo un slep para dar separacion y tampoco